# master theorem base case is constant?

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

Does Master Theorem assumes T(1) is constant? Say if I have an algorithm with time complexity: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1) and T(1) = O(logn), what is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: `T(1) = O(logn)` is nonsensical: the size of the problem can't be both parameterised and constant. Is it a typo?

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is that I have n points and m labels. Each point is assigned a label. m can be less than n. I want to do divide and conquer on labels instead of points. So my recursion becomes T(m) = 2T(m/2) + O(1) and the time complexity to solve the points with the same label is O(logn).  Is there any way to solve this? Or I get my equation wrong.

Comment: There are indeed ways to solve multivariable recurrence relations. Take a look at similar questions on Mathematics [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126396/methods-for-solving-two-variable-recurrence) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/solving-recurrence-relation-in-2-variables).

Answer (score 0):

For the recurrence relation: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)`, we have

- a = 2
- b = 2
- an O(1) time cost work outside the recursion

therefore the master theorem case 1 applies, and we have:

T(n) ∈ Θ(n ^ log2(2)) ⇒

T(n) ∈ Θ(n)

A recurrence relation defines a sequence based on an initial term. If a problem of size 1 is solved by the recurrence relation `T(1) = f(n)`, where f ∈ O(logn),  the value of T(1) can't be determined, i.e. makes no sense as a recurrence relation.

Comment: Can you see my comment above? I added more details to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `T(1) = O(logn)` does not make any sense. You basically states that some function that does not depend on `n` for some reason has a logarithmic complexity (thus depends on `n` in a logarithmic way).

`T(1), T(2), T(532143243)` are boundary conditions and can not depend on any parameter. They should be a number (`5`, `pi/e`, `sqrt(5) - i`)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's best just to try things out rather than relying on a Theorem.

```
T(m) = 2T(m/2) + O(1)
T(1) = O(logn)

T(2) = 2T(1) = 2log(n)
T(4) = 2T(2) = 4log(n)
T(8) = 2T(4) = 8log(n)
T(16) = 2T(8) = 16log(n)
T(32) = 2T(16) = 32log(n)
T(m) = 2T(m/2) = mlog(n)
```

In conclusion, your initial question is indeed nonsensical as others have pointed out because you are attempting to calculate `T(n)` when the same `n` is used in `T(1) = O(logn)`. But we can answer your second question that you have added as a comment.